# How to insert a query URL with ampersand in SharePoint 2010 HTML editor

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm working in SharePoint 2010, and creating an item in an "Announcement" type list. What I want to do is insert a link with a query in it:

```
https://www.yammer.com/company-name.com/#/threads/inGroup?type=in_group&feedId=1234567
```

I'm using the built-in SharePoint HTML editor to edit my text, and I inserted the link naively as:

```
<a href="https://www.yammer.com/company-name.com/#/threads/inGroup?type=in_group&feedId=1234567"> Yammer group </a>
```

However, when I exit the HTML editor, SharePoint automatically changes the code. The ampersand, used to separate the query arguments, gets replaced by %26, and as a consequence the link doesn't work as intended.

I've tried a number of workarounds for the "&" symbol, but SharePoint always substitutes in a way that makes the link useless (in IE9 at least):

```
& --> %26
&amp; --> %26
&#38; --> %26
\x26 --> %5cx26
```

Working with webparts, e.g. a content editor webpart, is not an option (the body of the list entries is HTML only).

How do I get the link to be passed/displayed correctly? I'm grateful for any ideas!

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

I came up finding the same issue and it looks like that the ampersand (&) sign appearing after the hash (#) sign is what makes SharePoint encode it.
As a Google search returned this post, I am replying it even if this was an old question.

I also found that not using "type=in_group" in the Yammer URL seemed to work fine. With only one argument left (feedID), there is no need for an ampersand and this may be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to write HTML directly in the text box which results in some of your symbols being escaped.

If you want to insert a link there is a hyperlink button which you can use and you wouldn't need to write the HTML markup yourself.

Comment: Using the link function as you suggested still doesn't work.  The link will work while you still have the editor open, but after saving the ampersand is replaced.